# Как правильно оформлять библиотеки?

Tags: javascript

Я оформил свою библиотеку так:

```
let name = (function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
    //То что нужно вынести
    };
})();
```

Но я не очень понимаю принципы работы `iife` и не понимаю правильно ли это ли нет?

Comment: не понятно что она делает, для чего там функция...  И что такое `iife`?

Comment: @Air функционал не имеет значения, IIFE это конструкция (function (){})()

Comment: Впервые вижу такую аббревиатуру...   ладно, не суть... да вот вопрос, если функция не имеет значения, в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Air вопрос в том что я хочу узнать как принято их оформлять, чтобы не засорять пространство имён.

Comment: Почитайте про CommonJS, AMD, UMD и до кучи ES6 импорты

Comment: @brachkoff, ты уже задавал такой вопрос, что не так с предыдущим вариантом?

Comment: Если это библиотека, как ей пользоваться? Пока это просто кусок кода с замыканием в анонимной функции и возвращённым объектом после немедленного её вызова.. Т.е. есть возможности для инкапсуляции неких переменных внутри замыкания и некий экспортируемый интерфейс. И всё? Где предполагается объявление `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что на этот вопрос нельзя дать однозначного ответа.

Есть гайдлайны вроде [такого](https://github.com/standard/standard) или [идиоматичного](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/).

Разные компании свои гайдлайны используют:

- [airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)
- [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)

Полезно было бы почитать [такие](https://medium.com/@kelin2025/so-you-wanna-use-es6-modules-714f48b3a953) статьи. Но выбор за вами. Я бы порекомендовал посмотреть популярные js библиотеки и делать по аналогии.

Comment: В данном случае оформление можно считать правильным?

Comment: @brachkoff я с клиентским js не работаю. В nodejs это было не правильным.